# Change file encoding for avro/hdfs

Tags: hdfs, python-3.6, avro

My intention is to read files from hdfs and parse them into json by using python. The files had been created by flume (twitter api), so I assume they are streamed avro files by default.

However, it seems avro is expecting UTF-8 but does get some other encoding provided by the file. What can I do to parse those files successfully?

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter

tf = avro.schema.Parse(open("/home/user/Data/hdfs/twitter_data/FlumeData.1534507350470", "rt").read())


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8f116b790f79> in <module>()
----> 1 tf = avro.schema.Parse(open("/home/user/Data/hdfs/twitter_data/FlumeData.1534507350470", "rt").read())

/usr/lib64/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 17: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: `/home/user/Data/hdfs/..` does not look like a HDFS file, rather a local file

Comment: When I access the file through a sparkContext, it's `hdfs://localhost:9000/home/user/Data/hdfs/twitter_data/FlumeData.1534507350470` and this works great because it's a valid hdfs directory. But avro.schema.Parse(open()) only works by using a normal path as a parameter and like you can see above, the parser at least recognizes the file.

Comment: since you cannot open the file with open()..